# Should I use a using statement/dispose if the object isn't actually going to be used in code?

Tags: c#, .net, process, idisposable

I'm working in some Winforms code right now, and I have come across lines like this several times:

```
...
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(someFileName);
...
```

...which just kicks off some process on the client machine, and completely forgets about it. `Process.Start(someFileName)` returns a `Process` type object, which implements `IDisposable`, but the code is not doing anything with the object, because the whole idea was to just trigger the process and forget about it.

In this case, should the `Process` object still be disposed, if we're not keeping it in memory at all? Something like:

```
using (System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(someFileName) { }
```

or

```
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(someFileName);
process.Dispose();
```

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(someFileName).Close();`

Comment: If it implements IDisposable then dispose it, a using() {} is the canonical way to do this.

Comment: The short answer is: Yes you should dispose. And it doesn't matter which of the two variants of code you use (assuming you don't put code into the using-block)

Answer (score 0):

`Process` objects holds *unmanaged resource(s)* (`HProcess` handle)

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,f8b2e604d6f1fe04

```
public class Process : Component {
    //
    // FIELDS
    //

    bool haveProcessId;
    int processId;
    bool haveProcessHandle;
    SafeProcessHandle m_processHandle; // <- This should be disposed
    bool isRemoteMachine;
    string machineName;
    ProcessInfo processInfo;
    Int32 m_processAccess;
...
```

And thus *should be disposed*. Using local variable (`var process = ...`) looks overshooting in the context, that's why I suggest

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(someFileName).Close();
```